# Passing js variable to php variable

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to pass the id value of the  tag that has just been clicked to a php file that is being loaded onto the page using greybox.

I got the id stored in a js variable called linkID and I can get it passing the correct id using location.href but this needs a page reload and doesnt work alongside greybox. Can and maybe how can I use Ajax to help send this info in the background?
Any help would be greatly appreciated?

The Javascript to get the id of the clicked a tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myCallback(caller)
{
  var linkID =caller.id; 
  location.href="species/butterfly.php?linkID=" + linkID;
  alert(linkID);
  }
</script>
```

The html a tag in index.php

```
<div id="stump">
<a href="#" id="2" class="hedgehog descript"  title="Hedgehog"
 rel="gb_page_center[1020, 550]" onclick="myCallback(this)"></a>
</div><!--close stump div -->
```

The butterfly.php page that is trying to recieve the id

```
<?php
// Retrieve the URL variables (using PHP).
$linkid = $_GET['linkID'];
echo "Number: ".$linkid;
?>
```

Comment: This is a pretty classic ajax use case. Are you using a javascript library like jQuery or Prototype? The syntax of the ajax call would differ depending on the library or if you are or aren't using one.

Comment: I am using both jquery and prototype for different things I made sure they werent conflicting. The greybox uses prototype.js so it would be this ajax call. Thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

```
var myCallback = function(caller){
    var linkID = caller.id; 

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","species/butterfly.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("linkID="+linkID;);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            alert("Request complete. Data: "+xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };

    alert(linkID);
 }
```

**EDIT:**

Pure GreyBox:

```
var myCallback = function(caller){
    var linkID = caller.id; 
    caller.href = "species/butterfly.php?linkID="+linkID;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I think it may work however what way would you write the <a href part of the tag <a href="#" makes the link not do anything? Thanks also for your speddy response

Comment: No problem, use this: `onclick="myCallback(this); return false;"` or `var myCallback function(caller){ /* other code */ return false; }`

Comment: No Im really not sure what is wrong if I leave href="#" as this it just loads the homepage in the greybox popup area. However if I put href="species/butterfly.php" here it brings in the butterfly.php page but the ajax request doesn't seem to have been sent or recieved as the id is not showing. If you have any other suggestions it would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Well, GreyBox is designed to only display the page defined in the `href=""`, what other result are you looking for?

Comment: oh right I wasnt aware of that! I think I might be making what I want to do more complicated than it should be. What I want to do is load information from a database into this greybox (butterfly.php) where the id the user has clicked on equals the id in the database.

Comment: Well, in that case, you might not want AJAX. Editing my answer to reflect a solution...

Answer (score 0):

This will convert js variable to php variable

```
<script>
function sud(){

javavar=document.getElementById("text").value;  

document.getElementById("rslt").innerHTML="<?php 
$phpvar='"+javavar+"'; 
echo $phpvar.$phpvar;?>";
}

function sud2(){
document.getElementById("rslt2").innerHTML="<?php 
echo $phpvar;?>";
}

</script> 
<body>
<div id="rslt">
</div>

<div id="rslt2">
</div>
<input type="text" id="text" />
<button onClick="sud()" >Convert</button>
<button onClick="sud2()">Once Again</button>

</body>
```