# Possible to pass a variable from jQuery with AJAX to PHP page and a session variable?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing javascript variable to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095531/passing-javascript-variable-to-php)

Hi

I wonder if it's possible to pass a variable from a jQuery script to a PHP-page and put the variable into a session variable like this:

`$_SESSION['mapZoomArea'] = (isset($_GET['mapza']) ? $_GET['mapza'] : "";`

I'm not sure how to pass the variable and the url to the server? Preciate some help!

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? You know that you have to use Ajax, so I assume you already had a look at `jQuery.ajax`(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Where are you stuck?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810204/passing-js-variable-to-php-variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810204/passing-js-variable-to-php-variable), [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130662/passing-javascript-variable-to-php-using-ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130662/passing-javascript-variable-to-php-using-ajax).

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+send+variable+php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a dedicated service specifically for writing this value into the session, you probably should make it a POST request (GET will work too, but GET requests should be for data retrieval, not for writing to the server).

Therefore, simply create a new PHP page, let's say "storezoomarea.php", and have jQuery make an Ajax POST request to that page:

```
$.ajax({url: "storezoomarea.php", type: "post", data: {"mapza": mapza}})
```

Then, on the server side, you can retrieve it from the _POST variable:

```
$_SESSION['mapZoomArea'] = (isset($_POST['mapza']) ? $_POST['mapza'] : "";
```

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't it be possible to pass several values like this: $.ajax({url: "PStoreZoomArea.php", type: "get", data: {"mapza": mapZoomArea, "mapc": mapCenter, "mapz": mapZoom}}) But it's not working!?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I'm not sure why it isn't working for you. But note that as I said, you should use type: "post" rather than type: "get" (or PHP won't make them available in the $_POST variable).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should use AJAX. Since you have JQuery available it is very simple.

More reading available here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Example:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "some.php",
   data: ({'mapza' : yourvariable}),
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

HTH :)

Comment: I would pass data in a dictionary (`{"mapza": yourvariable}`) rather than manually constructing a string (`"mapza=" + yourvariable"`). The latter approach will get you into trouble if you have special characters that need to be URL-encoded. (And yes, you could use `encodeURIComponent`, but then why bother using jQuery if you are going to do things by hand?)

Comment: agreed :) ... I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Not bad. Make sure you've called `session_start();` first. Pass the variable in as a query string, 'http://whatever.com/?mapza=yourvariablevaluehere'. You can do this with jQuery by:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'urlhere',
    data : { mapza : 'your variable value here' }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

Yes, you can pass that var to a php code, if you make an AJAX call, with jquery ($.Ajax(whatever)), and of course, in the file called with AJAX change the session var.